# How can i sure that my purchased used car is not a stolen piece?

Tags: old-cars

Please suggest me that how can i check before purchase that the used car is a stolen piece or need some repair in engine or other parts?

Comment: While this is a valid question, I think it falls way beyond the scope of MV _Maintenance & Repair_. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: This is clearly off topic based on [What topics can I ask about here?](http://mechanics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) Based on the number of responses however the community may feel otherwise, if so please comment or open a meta question about same. Thanks

Comment: This could be completely rewritten and still maintain some of the original intent: ala how do I check the VIN on this particular car?  Where can I find all the VIN-marked parts on the car?

Comment: I don’t think the last edit helps. From off-topic, it also went into “too broad” category, and combined two questions into one.

Answer (score 2):

The traffic department or DMV (depending on your country) can tell you everything about a car if you can obtain its VIN  number (sometimes called the chassis number) and/or engine code.

These numbers should be on the car's body work somewhere. Usually under the bonnet or on the inside of the driver's door frame. For instance, a Vauxhall's might look like this:

Chassis/VIN: W0N0Txxxxxxxxxxxx

Engine: C20LETxxxxxxxx

You could phone them, give them the number(s) and ask them

1. who the owner is,
2. whether the car was stolen,
3. whether the car has been scrapped,
4. whether it has any unpaid fines,
5. whether its license may be behind

Those are the most important questions. But you can also find out its original colour, year of manufacture, model designation, etc. if you're concerned about being sold a base-model dressed up as a deluxe-model.

Answer (score 0):

First, you have to check the number plate and make sure is it original or fake. And you can also deal with a reputed dealer to buy a car if it is used or a new one and i can advice you to contact with Rustys Auto Salvage.

Comment: What do you mean by “number plate”? If you mean licence plate, most cars for sale would not have it. And how does one go about determining its authenticity, whatever that is? Also, elaborate why do you recommend that specific service, and note your affiliation to it, please.

Answer (score 0):

In the US get the VIN number and go to the [CARFAX](http://reports.carfax.com/1/vin-carfax-20/) website — it’s not free, but it’s not prohibitively expensive, and it tracks vehicle’s complete history so you can find out if the car you are buying in Colorado was salvaged/scrapped in New Jersey due to hurricane Sandy for instance.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't get it directly from the licencing authority, Many countries have a variety of commercial 'car data check' type services that, for a small fee, will check the history of a vehicle from the VIN or registration/licence numbers, and will give you similar information to Juann's answer, and will also let you know if the car has any outstanding finance against it and whether it has previously been in an accident.